# Formulating mapping constraint(gecode)

Tags: constraint-programming, gecode

I need to express a constraint for 2 integer Arrays of the same size

```
x_i = x_j => y_i = y_j
```

in other words, there is an integer function such

```
x = f(y)
```

Is there any solutions for it?

Comment: Can't you just add corresponding Boolean expressions via simple C++ loop? Check out Boolean expressions and relations section in [documentation](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG.pdf)

Comment: the problem it's gonna be n^2 constraints in this case

Comment: How big are these arrays?